# How to Get Current Browser URL in php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i getting issue fetch current url .php?id=1 get id

i am using this code

```
$query = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path = pathinfo( $query );
$what_you_want = $path['basename'];
```

get .php but not get id

Comment: You need a GET array. I.e. `$var = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: use $id = $_GET['id']

Comment: look at `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: but first full path print after get id    path onlly print index .php  not print id

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

For more details on what info is available in the `$_SERVER` array, see the PHP manual

If you also need the query string (the bit after the ? in a URL), that part is in this variable:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  GET to get the value of id . You don't need to use  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

```
$id  = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
         if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
             $pageURL .= "s";
            }
           $pageURL .= "://";
            if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
                $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" .              $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
         $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
          }
        return $pageURL;
        }
```